# I don't understand the permission of either user or group

Tags: virtualbox, manjaro

I have trouble using virtualbox.

I only can see usb devices as only root.

To solve a problem I checked system permissions.

```
╭─ksoo@ksoo-pc /dev 
╰─$ cat /etc/group | grep $USER
wheel:x:998:ksoo
lp:x:991:cups,ksoo
sys:x:3:bin,ksoo
network:x:90:ksoo
scanner:x:96:ksoo
power:x:98:ksoo
ksoo:x:1000:
vboxusers:x:108:ksoo
╭─ksoo@ksoo-pc /dev 
╰─$ sudo ls -alhs vboxusb
total 0
0 drwxr-x---  3 root vboxusers   60 May 23 15:15 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 22 root root      3.7K May 23 15:15 ..
0 drwxr-x---  2 root vboxusers  180 May 23 15:15 001
╭─ksoo@ksoo-pc /dev 
╰─$ cd vboxusb
cd: permission denied: vboxusb
```

/dev/vboxusb has rwxr-x--- permission. And ksoo belongs to vboxusers.

Why can't ksoo access to /dev/vboxusb ?

Comment: I'm assuming you just barely added ksoo to vboxusers. If so run `su - ksoo` for the change to take effect. Then you'll be able to cd into that directory.

Comment: @n8te what do you mean "barely"? I have the same issue, I added user to the `vboxusers` via `sudo adduser <user> vboxusers`. And yes `su -l` worked. Could you please explain your assumption? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.